# Cannot dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, windows-10

I want to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on an ASUS VivoBook X512FJ. I've already installed Windows 10, but I have problems installing Ubuntu. I tried 18.04 and 19.04 - came to the same problem:

I already did the following:

1. made space for Ubuntu to install using Disk Manager in Windows:
   [image: Picture of partitions]

   The output of `sudo fdisk -l` when booted from the USB stick is:

   ```
   Disk /dev/loop0: 1.9 GiB, 2027323392 bytes, 3959616 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Disk /dev/loop1: 89.3 MiB, 93581312 bytes, 182776 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Disk /dev/loop2: 53.7 MiB, 56315904 bytes, 109992 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Disk /dev/loop3: 151 MiB, 158343168 bytes, 309264 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Disk /dev/loop4: 4 MiB, 4218880 bytes, 8240 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Disk /dev/sda: 14.4 GiB, 15472047104 bytes, 30218842 sectors
   Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: dos
   Disk identifier: 0x46f8e7bf

   Device         Boot   Start         End Sectors  Size Id Type
   /dev/sda1  *                  0 4095999 4096000        2G  0 Empty
   /dev/sda2           4066772 4074259        7488  3.7M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
   ```
2. I burned the iso image on the USB drive
3. Fast boot and secure boot are disabled
4. When I go through the installation I don't see the window where you can choose installation type (I.E. "Something else"): it just goes through and the only disk that I can install Ubuntu to is that USB with an image.

The screen where I get stuck:

[image: the screen where I get stuck]

5. I updated the BIOS/UEFI. After that when I choose "try Ubuntu before installing" it first shows Ubuntu loading screen and then I see this:
   [Picture of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jcbj.jpg)

Questions:

1. Can someone confirm I boot from UEFI mode?
   [image: Can someone confirm I boot from UEFI mode?]
2. How do I install Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you please share your disk partitions with me so, I can help you with it? I am sure that their is some thing wrong in this pic and I can help you cope with it once you share your disk partitions with me. I have installed Ubuntu several times I am sure I can help you.

Comment: Where is the partition you allocated for Ubuntu. If it is the unallocated one. Than I suggest you to allocate partitions for Ubuntu from Windows disk management tool. Because when I installed Ubuntu i was getting different harddisk size from windows and different size fo linux. Like my hardisk was 167GB as shown by windows but Ubuntu showed 180GB. However, that is not the issue. You just select your hard drive from the `Boot loader installations dropdown menu` and continue. Hope that helps!

Comment: It is the unallocated one. How can I do this from Winows disk manager? I am struggeling finding a way to do this.

Comment: Is Windows hibernated/fast start up on? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Be sure to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Windows was not hibernated/fast start up was not on. I tried this before. Thank you. How can I be sure that I boot in UEFI boot mode. I am reading those posts and it's very hart to understand what is what and why something helps. I am pretty lost with what is BIOS UEFI, how can I see the difference or where do I check and so on ... Thank you all for helping me, I hope something will help ...

Comment: From what I see, there are only `/dev/loopN` and `/dev/sda` disks recognized. loop are mounted images and sda is your Data traveler 3.0. It seems like your disks are not even recognized by Ubuntu installation. That is why it cannot install on a disk it doesn't see. It has been a long time since I have seen something like this. Theoretically it should be possible to add driver for that disk during installation. First you have to get that driver from hardware manufacturer.

Comment: To check whether you booted in uefi mode or not, `ls /sys/firmware/efi`.

Comment: So if I run this command and it gives me a list of files that means that folder exists and that I booted in UEFI mode?

Comment: I'll still look for SSD drivers but for now I cannot find them. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @LukaMatevžić Yes, exactly, so have you booted into uefi mode or not?

Comment: Ok, I booted in UEFI mode then.

Comment: **Luka**, Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **:-)** I edited your question to make it more clear for myself and everyone.  The issue is that your hard disk is not recognized by the Linux kernel which is what fuels Ubuntu.  When you see the [following screen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WONqn.jpg), please press [e] to edit and remove `quiet, splash` and add `acpi=off` and try again. Then leave a comment **@Fabby**

Comment: Also if SSD, have you updated UEFI and firmware for SSD? Even new SSD may need firmware update to be correctly seen. When you boot Ubuntu you get one of these two screens: Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your help. @Fabby tried your suggestion unfortunatelly it did not work.

Comment: @oldfred: hi, I first tried to update firmware for SSD card, but since I cannot find the manufacturer I couldn't find it. The manufacturer is "(Standard disk drives)". So I then updated the BIOS and when I try to "try Ubuntu before installing" I get a Ubuntu loading screen and then the photo that I'll post in the question.

Comment: and also before the firmware update the first partiton on the USB was purple and partiton 2 was black. After the update they are both black. If I choose the second one and "try Ubuntu before installing" and then start installing Ubuntu it crashes right before the "installation type" screen.

Comment: Does this show more info on drive? `sudo lshw -C disk -short` or even more detail including serial number? `sudo lshw -class disk
`

Comment: **LukaMatevžić** 2 things to do: 1. re-download ubuntu and use a different USB drive 2. turn `acpi=on`. if you've done all those and you still see no change, your specific disk manufacturer is a no-name white product with only Windows support through drivers and then you'll have to swap it out as Linux support will be none-existent...  **:-(**  cc @oldfred

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your help and time. I redownloaded Ubuntu on a different USB drive - did not help. I also contacted Asus support and they advised me to use only Windows since the information about manufacturer is not avaliable. Since I am tired of trying this I will stop for now. But in the future if I decide to upgrade/swap the SSD I'll let you know. For now I'll just use the Ubuntu in VM. And for sure I am not buying anything from Asus again! Thanks again for your help. It is truly a great communty here!